# Recursively add child nodes to TreeView C#

Tags: c#, forms, treeview, treeviewitem

I didn't think this would be that hard to do but I have been stuck on this for the last 45 minutes or so. I am trying to make a recursive function that finds files in a directory and add them to the TreeView.
This is my method so far:

```cs
        private void RecursiveAddToTree(string path, TreeNode parent)
        {
            var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (var directory in directories)
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(getItemOrDirectoryName(directory)) {ImageIndex = 0, SelectedImageIndex = 1};
                //this is where I need to add the child node to the parent node
                RecursiveAddToTree(directory,node);
            }
            
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(getItemOrDirectoryName(file)) {ImageIndex = 0, SelectedImageIndex = 0};
                //this is where I need to add the child node to the parent node
            }
        }
```

I'm looking for a way to add a child node to a parent node given the parent node, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Is this winforms? Can you not just do `parent.Nodes.Add(node);`?

Comment: @RufusL Thanks! that worked, I was trying to do something like `parent.Add(node)` but I wasn't seeing that option. Since nobody was replying I ended up making a slow and convoluted solution but I was able to replace all of that with this one line of code. I would mark this as solved but this is a comment and not an answer so I can't

Comment: This way, it will be a long and slow task. Imagine when pass `c:` as the path parameter. Too much. I think you should populate just one level at a time and handle the `TreeView.BeforeExpand` event to populate (if not already) the contents of the selected directory, again just the top level. Also, you need to skip the `UnauthorizedAccessException` when you catch one.

Comment: @dr.null for my use case it will most likely never go beyond 3 or 4 folders, but I do agree that if you are working with displaying large filesystems in a tree populating the items with BeforeExpand would be better